# Prove that $m$ divides the characteristic of $R.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, positive-characteristic

I want to answer this question:

Let $R$ be a ring (with $1$), and let $H$ be the cyclic subgroup of $(R,+)$ generated by $1.$ The characteristic of $R$ is $n$ if $H\cong \mathbb{Z}_{n},$ and is $0$ if $H \cong \mathbb{Z}.$\
(a) Show that, if $a \in R$ has additive order $m,$ then $m$ divides the characteristic of $R.$

**My question is:**

I get this hint to answer it:  If $H \cong \mathbb{Z}$, this is obvious (why?). So assume $H\cong \mathbb{Z}_{n}$ for some $n$. Remind yourself that $(R,+)$ is an abelian group. Use the following fact from elementary group theory.

Lemma: Suppose that $G $is a group with identity $e$, and $x$ in $G$ has finite order t. If $x^s=e$ for some integer $s$, then $t$ divides $s$.

But I do not understand how this hint will lead me to prove that $m$ divides the characteristic of $R.$ could anyone help me in answering this question, please?

Comment: You seem to have provided much detail. But the first part is just the question. The second part is the hint. The third part simply says you don't know how to do it. So I'd say this question needs to show more efforts...

Comment: @WhatsUp Sure I will .... but I need a tiny help ....is there a more handy definition of **the characteristic  of R** that we can use in our case here? The definition given in the question is making it hard to me to conclude anything

Comment: @Smart20 For a ring $R$ with identity $1$, the characteristic of $R$ is the smallest positive integer such $n$ such that $n1=0$. If such integer does not exist, then the characteristic of $R$ is said to be $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case 1: The characteristic of $R$ is $0$.
Clearly, $m$ divides $0$ so this is obvious.

Case 2: The characteristic of $R$ is $n$ where $n\neq 0$.
Note that $$na=n(1a)=(n1)a=0a=0.$$
Since $m$ is the additive order of $a$, by the Lemma you stated, $m$ must divides $n$.

Comment: Why $(n1) = 0$?

Comment: @Smart20 As I said in the comment, the characteristic of $R$ is $n$ means that $n$ is the smallest positive integer such that $n1=0$.

Comment: Yeah sorry I realized that but I forgot to delete the comment.