# Help understanding: Let R be a ring with identity. If 1 has order n, then the characteristic of R is n.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, characteristics

This is from Judson's Abstract Algebra textbook.

We define the $\underline{characteristic}$ of a ring R to be the least positive integer $n$ s.t. $nr=0, \forall r\in R$. If there is no such n, we say that the characteristic is 0.

Lemma 16.18: Let R be a ring with identity. If 1 has order n, then the characteristic of R is n.

I am having a hard time understanding this Lemma. First, why do we suppose 1 has order n?
I read in another similar [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3825857/prove-that-m-divides-the-characteristic-of-r) that this means that n1 = 0, but I do not see that connection and how that could be derived from Lemma 16.18.

Could someone please give me an example to help understand this.

Could an application of Lemma 16.18 be the following problem:

What is the characteristic of the field formed by the set of matrices

F=
$\{
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
\}$
with entries in $\mathbb{Z}_2$?

Answer: Characterisitic of this field is 2, since $1+1=2(1)\equiv0\mod2$. So, 1 has order 2.

Comment: If 1 has order $n$, then $1$ added to itself $n$ times equals zero. But $n1$ *is* $1$ added to itself $n$ times, so $n1=0$. For example, if $1$ has order $3$, then $3(1)=1+1+1=0$.

Comment: Thank you. Is this always the case in $\mathbb{Z}_n, n\geq2$?

Comment: Isn't this the _definition_ of the characteristic of a ring? If not, then what is the definition of characteristic that you are using?

Comment: We define the $\underline{characteristic}$ of a ring R to be the least positive integer $n$ s.t. $nr=0, \forall r\in R$. If there is no such n, we say that the characteristic is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $n$ has order $1$. Then $n$ is the least positive integer such that $\underbrace{1 + {}\dotsm {} + 1}_{\text{$n$ times}} = 0$. It follows that, for every $r \in R$, $nr = 0$ since
$$
nr = \underbrace{r + {}\dotsm{} + r}_{\text{$n$ times}} = r(\underbrace{1 + {}\dotsm {} + 1}_{\text{$n$ times}}) = r0 = 0
$$
Moreover $n$ is the least positive integer such that, for all $r \in R$, $nr = 0$ since $n$ is the order of $1$. Thus $R$ has characteristic $n$.

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense. Why do we distinguish $n\times r$ (nr) as $r+\ldots+ r$ (n times)? How are these notations different? 

 And, would you know if my example is an appropriate application of Lemma 16.18?